# read strings with pd.readcsv() and convertes always creates objects, not strings

Tags: python, pandas

I use pandas pd.read_csv() to read and  process a column of strings with a converter function while reading.  I get 'object' as data type, but string would be much more space efficient.

Can I somehow convince pd.read_csv() to make the column of type 'string' from the beginning? I know how to convert later, but this may become a memory issue, the dataset is large.

```
f  = lambda x: "/".join(x.split('/')[1:5])

pd.read_csv(..., convertes={'path':f}, ...)

I use pandas 1.0.3 and python 3.8.2
```

Would be even better if I could create type category (of strings) from the beginning ...

thank you,

Heiner

Answer (score 0):

Pandas maps the strings to object type that is why you are getting an object as dtype.

You can see the different mappings of python type to pandas dtype below.
[image]

[img src](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html)